# Read the string and get the file name in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

I have set of Java files in a folder. I need to search all the java files inside the folder to find string value and if i find the string value i need to print the file name.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Advance thank if anyone gives idea or any sample program in java

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What have you tried ? please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you misunderstood your assignment in some way.
Because I think there is no use case for searching java files for a string - It is either a text file or it is code - Nevertheless:

how to list all files in this dir:

```
private static void getAllFiles(File curDir) {
File curDir = new File(".");
File[] filesList = curDir.listFiles();
for(File f : filesList){
 if(f.isDirectory()){
  getAllFiles(f);
 }
 if(f.isFile()){
  System.out.println(f.getName());
 }
}
```

if you want to search for a string in the code, use some kind of readers (where it currently outputs the name of the file) to get the content of the file and check if the file contains the string you are searching for. Without having any more information on your exercise, it is hard to provide you with any further assistent.

Comment: "_I think there is no use case for searching java files for a string_" - My IDE does that.

Comment: How to read the file i tried with scanner but not able to fetch the file name